# Allure reports displays disabled test cases as Unknown instead of Skipped

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

I use Java Selenium TestNG and Allure reports combination for my test framework. My problem is Allure shows strange behavior when I disable some test cases using `enabled = false` Allure shows does test cases as Unknown. I would like to make those test cases displayed as Skipped.

Is there a way to do it either with a setting or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open issue with [allure-java](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/issues/369)

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around for this. Once the result folder is generated. I will run the script to remove `skipped` test on the `.json` file. After this script run the `allure` report generation command.

```html
cd ./allure-results
ls
for D in *;
do
CREDENTIALS=$(jq -c '. | .status' $D)
a=$CREDENTIALS
b='"skipped"'
if [[ $a == $b ]]
then
rm $D
fi
done
ls
```